# database is not updating any solution

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$npoint = $re - $point;

$uery = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` ='$npoint' 
WHERE `int` = '$int'";

$uery = "INSERT INTO `teams`(`teams`, `int`, `name`, `points`, `mpoint`, `day`) 
VALUES ('$p','$int','$name','$npoint','$point','$today')";
```

Comment: You never execute your queries

Comment: Holy mother of naming.

Answer (score -2):

Each variable should be surrounded with brackets... i.e.: {$variable}.

Also, where is your SQL Connection Initialization? Where is your SQL Query Execution? May I also suggest better namespacing? Also, if the column `int` is indeed an integer, then you should not be putting quotes around the '{$int}' variable. That is also to be said if you're using floats...

Comment: 1. This answer is incorrect. 2. This is more of a comment than an answer. 3. Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.